# Linear Memory Container With Persistent Lookups?

Tags: c++, memory, vector, containers, allocation

I've been scouring the net looking for a container that handles this scenario best:

1. Linear memory (no gaps like an object pool or allocator would have)
2. Some way to give a reference to an object in container that remains persistent between adds/removals. Or a way to search quickly to find original objects.
3. Decently fast adds to end and removals from middle (but no inserts required)

So far the only solution I've been able to find is to use an `std::vector` and when a removal takes place I update all reference indices above the current index being removed. This just seems bad, looking for any other solution that would be more efficient.

Comment: Linear memory as in ordered? Or is unordered okay too?

Comment: Do the objects have any relation i.e. can be sorted?

Comment: Cannot be sorted, must retain original order

Comment: @user1201584 Must retain original order or just needs to verify number 2? (And reguardless of whether or not it will be, can the elements be compared)?

Comment: Removal would require moving elements in the container to fill the gap. This precludes any kind of no-maintenance persistent reference or pointer (you would have to update them as you found with `std::vector`). In other words, requirements 1 and 2 are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a horrible idea. I haven't tried it at all so there is probably more than a few bugs.

```
  template <typename T>
  class InsaneContainter {
  public:
     class MemberPointer {
        friend class InsaneContainer;
        size_t idx_;
        InsaneContainter* parent_;
     public:
        MemberPointer(InsaneContainter* parent,size_t idx) idx_(idx),parent_(parent){}
        T& operator*() {
           parent->members[idx_];
        }
     };
     friend class MemberPointer;
     using Handle = std::shared_ptr<MemberPointer>;
     Handle insert(const T& t) {
        members.push_back(std::make_tuple(T{t},Handle{new MemberPointer{this,members.size()}));
        return std::get<1>(members.back());
     }
     Handle GetHandle(size_t idx) {
       return std::get<1>(members[idx]);
     }
     void delete(size_t idx) {
         //swap with end
         std::swap(members[idx],members.back());
         std::get<1>(members[idx])->idx_=idx;
         members.pop_back();
     }
private:
     std::vector<std::tuple<T,std::shared_ptr<MemberPointer>> members_;
};
```

The idea is that, at insertion time, you'll receive a handle that will always have O(1) find and delete. While it is otherwize O(n) to find the object, once you find it you can get the handle which will stay up to date.

The usage of such a structure is...limited to say the least so I suspect and X vs Y problem here.

Comment: I think this was pretty neat. One question though. Why do you say lookup is O(n)? Shouldn't std::vector::operator[] be O(1)? Or is something else going on in the GetHandle function that I'm missing? Or are you refering to something else when you say "While it is otherwize O(n) to find the object"?

Comment: @warsac It is the "find" operation, i.e. Given element X,get the handle to X will take O(n). As long as you have the handle you can do what you want in constant time, but if you don't have a handle then you're a little screwed.

Comment: This is definitely an interesting solution - however I can't mark this the answer because I found a faster solution for my specific issue

Answer (score 0):

Through lots of performance testing I found the fastest method for the general case below:

1.) Use a pool allocator that stores free memory regions.

2.) Use free memory region list to copy occupied data linearly into temporary memory at every "gap" in the pool.

This works best for me due to the nature of add/removes in my program (resulting in low fragmentation)